# YT API - Pulling different "video lengths" for YouTube videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Lately our clients noticed a discrepancy in the video length metric, as it seems like we're getting 2 different lengths in YT and in the API call.

For example, We got the duration from YouTube's API. (For the following video)
CTM 1556 Google UAC CO 6s

API response shows 7 seconds.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJoQaNXpcpI

On YouTube we see that the length is 6 seconds:

API docs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration

API call list (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with **contentDetails as "part" parameter**.

Please help us understand why we are getting 2 different parameters, and what needs to be changed.

Comment: Probably is for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard that an additional second is added to the value in the duration of the video. If you consider this is an error, consider post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why having a single second of difference bother you, may you explain why ?

YouTube UI may approximate (flooring or ceiling) differently from the YouTube Data API v3 (according to ffmpeg your video is 6.08 seconds long) or as mentioned] [Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes) said it is maybe due to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as it is specified in [Videos: list#contentDetails.duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration).

By web-scraping the YouTube UI you can get the exact duration as my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0f1f4281cbd3f70eca2d0c7feffc61089c5c01d5/videos.php#L90) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com) does. You can test it by requesting
https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=contentDetails&id=eJoQaNXpcpI
You will get the duration you are looking for in `item["contentDetails"]["duration"]`.

Note: Your mail.google.com links don't work. Try in incognito tab next time you have a doubt.